# \savebox in page header with redefinable commands

Tags: macros, header-footer, boxes, fancyhdr

I'm making a document class with some redefinable commands for page headers. However, I'm running into the following issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% In custom document class
\newcommand{\foo}{old header}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \newsavebox\mybox
    \sbox\mybox{\foo}
    \chead{\usebox\mybox}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

% In user tex file
\renewcommand{\foo}{new header}

\begin{document}
    Page 1
    \newpage
    Page 2
\end{document}
```

This produces
[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]

How can I allow the user to redefine these commands, but still use `\sbox` so I can use `\wd` inside the page header for positioning purposes?

Comment: Be careful that `fancyhdr` wants the header height to be the same across the document; if it finds `\headheight` is not sufficient to contain the header, it changes it from the next page, which could lead to various problems.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the tip. Where is this documented? What should one do if differently-sized headers are desirable?

Comment: You should fix a head height that suffices for the tallest header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can proceed in this way.

- First of all, declare the new box outside the command `\fancypagestyle`
- When you want to change the header, issue both the commands

  ```
  \renewcommand{\foo}{new header}
  \pagestyle{mystyle}
  ```

  inside your document.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% In custom document class
\newcommand{\foo}{old header}

\newsavebox\mybox % declare it outside

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \sbox\mybox{\foo}
    \chead{\usebox\mybox}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
    Page 1
    \newpage
    \renewcommand{\foo}{new header}
    \pagestyle{mystyle}
    Page 2
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Since it is supposed to go in a document class, I suggest you to define a new command `\newheader` and use it in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% In custom document class
\newcommand{\foo}{}
\newcommand{\newheader}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\foo}{#1}%
  \pagestyle{mystyle}%
}

\newsavebox\mybox % declare it outside

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \sbox\mybox{\foo}
    \chead{\usebox\mybox}
}
\newheader{old header}

\begin{document}
    Page 1
    \newpage
    \newheader{new header}
    Page 2
\end{document}
```